# integration of a multi-variable function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was studying fluid mechanics, and I came across an integration of a multi-variable function.

The question was, what is

$\int x \mathrm{dz}$ (when z = $x^2 + y^2$) ?

Using WolframAlpha, the result is JUST $\int\ x dz$ (when z = $x^2 + y^2$) = '$xz + Constant$'

- it considered $x$ being a constant, and integrate as indicated.

  $\int\ x dz$ = $x\int\ dz$ = $xz + Constant$

---

In my opinion, $z$ is 'multi-variable' function of '$x$' and '$y$'
and it means that when z changes, x and y changes respectively.

(if $z$ increases from zero to $z$, then $x$ and $y$ also increases from zero to x and y)

and the change of z can be expressed with 'total derivative' ($\large{dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy}$)

using this,  i get $\int\ x dz$ = ${\int}\ x ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy) =\int x (2xdx + 2ydy) = \int 2x^2dx + \int 2xydy  = \frac{1}{3}x^3 +xy^2 + Constant$

Why is this process wrong? Why considering the change of $x$ with $\mathrm{dz}$ makes integration wrong?

Comment: sorry for not appending the hyperlink. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2C+int+x+dz)